# Finding the Count for a String on Multiple Zipped Files in Multiple Directories (non aggregated)

Tags: grep, string, zip, gzip, wc

I'm trying to figure out the number of lines that contain the strings "event" and "type". The files I want to search through are in multiple folders and are zipped. I'm able to get an aggregated count of what I'm looking for, but my goal is to have the count displayed for each file. This is what I'm currently using:

> zcat
>   /folder1/{folderA,folderB,folderC}/folder2/folder3/result-2018-05-1* |
>   grep 'event' | grep 'type' | wc -l

And my output is:

```
86446
```

But I want my output to look like:

```
result-2018-05-10.log.gz: 1000
result-2018-05-11.log.gz: 3000
result-2018-05-12.log.gz: 20000
result-2018-05-13.log.gz: 4446
result-2018-05-14.log.gz: 12000
result-2018-05-15.log.gz: 10000
result-2018-05-16.log.gz: 15000
result-2018-05-17.log.gz: 5000
result-2018-05-18.log.gz: 6000
result-2018-05-19.log.gz: 10000
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only two tests, this should be enough:

```
zgrep -E -c 'event.*type|type.*event' /folder1/{folderA,folderB,folderC}/folder2/folder3/result-2018-05-1*
```

Testing if a line contains `type` and  `event` is the same as testing if it contains `type` followed later by `event` or `event` followed later by `type`. This wouldn't scale well if a 3rd test was needed.

Then adding something like `| sed 's#^.*/##'` should give the exact result in the question.

---

UPDATE:

For something more generic, a loop seems better, so:

```
for i in /folder1/{folderA,folderB,folderC}/folder2/folder3/result-2018-05-1*; do
    printf '%s: ' "$(basename "$i")"
    zcat < "$i" | grep 'filter1' | grep 'filter 2' | grep 'filter3' | wc -l
done
```

Comment: I'm actually grepping a lot of strings, I limited it to two to simplify the question. But this is still good to know! Thanks!

Comment: so I added a more generic case. would that be fine?

Comment: if you think this was the solution you should mark it as the solution